# jQuery same class

Tags: jquery, html, video

I'm editing the way to control videos in html 5 for my project with layer overlays and play and pause with one click. The problem is that im controlling a lot of videos with the same class and when I play one video, another video play, so i don't know how to solve it.

This my code.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.videobox').click(function () {
        if ($('.test').get(0).paused) {
            $('.videobox').css({
                opacity: 0
            });
            $('.test').get(0).play();
        } else {
            $('.test').get(0).pause();
            $('.videobox').css({
                opacity: 0.5
            });
        }
        e.preventDefault();

    });
    $('.test').bind("ended", function () {
        $('.videobox').css({
            opacity: 0.5
        });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="videobox" style="position: absolute; margin-left: 23px; z-index: 500; background-color: #000; opacity: 0.5; width: 473px; height: 474px;">
    <img src="image/camera.png" style="padding-top: 200px;">
</div>
<video class="test" width="473" height="474">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<div class="videobox" style="position: absolute; margin-left: 23px; z-index: 500; background-color: #000; opacity: 0.5; width: 473px; height: 474px;">
    <img src="image/camera.png" style="padding-top: 200px;">
</div>
<video class="test" width="473" height="474">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie2.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to work within the context of the event target, using `this` and traversing the DOM to the other elements you need:

```
$('.videobox').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var video = $this.next('video')[0];

    if (video.paused) {
        $this.css({
            opacity: 0
        });
        video.play();
    } else {
        video.pause();
        $this.css({
            opacity: 0.5
        });
    }
    e.preventDefault();

});
$('.test').bind("ended", function () {
    $(this).prev('.videobox').css({
        opacity: 0.5
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question at first.  It looks like you want one button to play several videos at once.  The trick is here in your code:

```
$('.test').get(0).play();
```

You're getting the first element in the array of items which match '.test', and toggling that one, instead of every element.  You can treat that as a pseudo array instead, and iterate through:

```
var pArr = $('.test');
for (var ii=0; ii < pArr.length; ii++)
{
    pArr.get(ii).play();
}
```

You'll need to do the same for 'pause', but you shouldn't need to modify your pause detection unless you want to get fancier with error handling.